# How to access values from list of maps in Apache camel message body

Tags: arraylist, apache-camel, maps

Perhaps this is easy, but I am somehow not able to crack it yet. Message body for an exchange is basically a list of maps with both key & value being string. As example,

`[{'key'='val1'}, {'key'='val2'},...]`

I am using *simple* expression to set this as a property which I would be using in subsequent routes. This is how I am setting it:

`.setProperty("myProperty", simple("${body}"))`

But this sets the complete body. I just want to (somehow) set only the values part to avoid setting the **entire** list of maps. What I have tried and not working so far:

```
.setProperty("myProperty", simple("${body}['key']"))
.setProperty("myProperty", simple("${body}[*]['key']"))
.setProperty("myProperty", simple("${body}[0]['key']")) // this returns only the first value, I want all
```

Any idea/suggestion how can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can just make a Processor and in it, with the help of ordinary Java, transfer everything from the body to the properties as it should (for example, using stream API)

Comment: Are you allowed to use groovy here?

Comment: @Greenev, unfortunately not. Currently working with Java only.

Comment: @AlexeyYakunin, with Processors and Java-code, this is easy to do. However, I was looking for something that can be done directly with SIMPLE expressions. I have learnt it that SIMPLE is not so flexible also. Anyway thanks for your tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access every level of your body with [Simple](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html) expressions:

```
${body} // get whole list of maps
${body[0]} // get first map in the list (index 0)
${body[0][key]} // get value of key "key" from the first map in the list
```

What you cannot do in a [Simple](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html) expression is a conversion of your data structure in another one.

However, you can simply plug a Java bean into your route

```
from("direct:start")
    ...
    .bean(MyConversionBean.class)
    ...;
```

And do the conversion with Java

```
public class MyConversionBean {
    public List<String> convertBody() {
        // extract all values (or whatever) with Java;
        return listOfValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have learnt this now, that with SIMPLE expressions are for simple use-cases (:D) and complex cases are to be avoided. Thanks for your help :)